# How to undo place embedded in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

How can I undo `File > Place Embedded` image once the file has been saved?

Is there a method to get rid of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Delete the layer to remove the contents
- Right-click/Control-click the Layer in the **Layers Panel** and choose one:

  - `Relink to File` to change what file is embeded
  - `Relink to Library Graphic` to link to a library graphic
  - `Replace Contents` to, well replace the contents of the smart object
  - `Convert to Linked` to convert an embedded file to a linked file.

[image]

Comment: This worked for me → Delete the layer to remove the contents

Comment: Yes. It's common to merely delete a layer if you no longer want that layer's contents.

Comment: You have written many other points what are they for ?

Comment: I explained what they are for in the answer.